# Efficient way to check record uniqueness during bulk insert in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm inserting 1000 or more records in MySQL table with a single query. I'm generating query through PHP loop which is something like this :

```
INSERT INTO `favorite_colors` (`ID`, `person_id`, `email`)
VALUES
(1, 1, '1@yellow.com'),
(2, 1, '2@yellow.com'),
(3, 2, '2@blue.com'),
(4, 2, '2@blue.com'),
(5, 3, '1@green.com');
```

This data is coming from a large CSV file which may have duplicate entries. Is there any way if I want to check the uniqueness of records based on two columns before inserting those in table. I don't want to check every single record in loop because I think that is not an efficient way to do this. My database doesn't have unique constraint so duplicate entries can be inserted easily. Database is old and already has duplicate entries so I can't just add unique constraint. 
I need a way to verify these bulk records from database if any record already exist. I need to show these records separately which are already exist in database.

Comment: See INSERT IGNORE. With appropriate indexes, there's no need to 'check' anything

Comment: I don't have unique constraint in my database with which database can identify duplicate.

Comment: So, why not fix that!?!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle this at php end simply create a hash for each value and before creating the query check for it's existence e.g.

```
$already_done = array();
foreach ($csvRecords as $record)
{
   $unique_hash = md5($record['person_id'].$record['email']);
   if (!in_array($unique_hash, $already_done))
   {
      $already_done[] = $unique_hash;
      // create sql insert query here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all ID looks like primary key, so what you need is not perfect solution because you will have different records for the same ID. Anyway, below is solution for what you asked.

I assume you get elements from some structure, i.e. array:

```
$rec = ['ID' => 1, 'person_id' => 1, 'email' => '1@yellow.com'];
```

So you can create some control array:

```
$added = [];
```

Then for each record you join fields:

```
$line = $rec['ID'] . '_' . $rec['person_id'] . "_" . $rec['email'];
```

Assuming ID and person_id are integers, you guaranteed uniqueness with underscore.

Then you check:

```
if(!isset($added[$line])) {
    $added[$line] = true;

    // proceed insert here
}
```

You can also try to convert $line to some unique hash